# Error in testing javascript with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am testing using Mocha following code. I included this javascript file in the testfile.I am trying to test function getLabels gut somehow it calls function populateTable (i am not calling it anywhere) and i get error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function ". How to avoid it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(populateTable, 0);

    function populateTable() {
        var fetchRecords = function() {

        }
        fetchRecords();
        $('#table').DataTable({

        });
    }

    function getLabels(labels) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jquery in the head of your html?

Also, you are calling populateTable(), in this line

```js
setTimeout(populateTable, 0);
```

You could comment that line out and replace it getLabels(labels); to test that function.

Comment: yes, you are right. Can i mock somehow as soon as this function is called just replace it with something.

Comment: This is automated test cases. I can't comment on the fly. I am able to test the getlabels function but the error is also there.